# Weird topology when using subdivision on a cylinder

Tags: mesh, subdivision-surface, topology

I'm creating a cylindrical shape and I'm getting weird topology when use subdivision surface modifier, I tried to add loops across the Y axis of the cylinder, but it made the edges on the Y axis sharp which I don't want. I spent some time trying to figure out how to solve it, but I couldn't find a solution...

[image: Strange behavior in object mode]

[image: Mesh in edit mode (1)]

[image]

Observation: The red loops are tightning loops that I have marked.

Comment: Maybe the best is to switch to a 32 vertices cylinder then use this topology: https://www.zupimages.net/up/23/26/hnhy.jpg

Comment: Woah it works, much thanks. But why was it happening and why does it solve it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch to a 32 vertices cylinder and choose the following topology, it will fix your shading problem (16 vertices leaves faces that are too large to avoid the pinching effects, as they are bending much more):

[image]